# What is I/O variance applying to Cloud Storage or HDFS?

Tags: hadoop, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, hdfs, variance

According to Google Cloud documentation,

> Cloud Storage may increase I/O variance. In many situations, Cloud Storage has a higher I/O variance than HDFS. This can be problematic if you have consistent I/O requirements, such as an application backed by HBase or another NoSQL database.

Can someone provide an example of variance? What does it mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means the rate of access is highly variable, or not consistent within a threshold.

Any cloud object storage will have higher variance compared to dedicated filesystems since they're multi-tenant

The comment, in general, is saying you wouldn't use GCS as a backend for a database (specifically HBase, Kudu, other Hadoop databases) as it'll introduce latency into these commonly low-latent systems, even though GCS can be used as the backing HDFS storage layer

Answer (score 0):

You can translate I/O to reads (input) and writes (output)
When read or write rate fit in a narrow range, you can easily decide on resource planning from network bandwidth to RAM and CPU.

As I/O variance increases, you have a wider range of read and write rates and deploying an optimized infrastructure becomes harder.

as @OneCricketeer mentioned, the higher variance in cloud storage could be result of multi tenancy and deployment of a large diversity of services.

One way to mitigate this problem is to divide services into multiple I/O variance ranges (i.e: databases, object storage, file storage etc.).